# CoreData Cache Error with NSPredicate

Tags: ios, if-statement, nspredicate

Why does this produce a caching error after adding the `if statements` to the `NSPredicate`? The error arrives after I attempt to filter the results based on the title of the UITABLEVIEW.

I get the following error:

```
CoreData: FATAL ERROR: The persistent cache of section information does not match the current configuration.  You have illegally mutated the NSFetchedResultsController's fetch request, its predicate, or its sort descriptor without either disabling caching or using +deleteCacheWithName
```

I have looked at other similar errors but can't relate them to my code.

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"ExcerciseInfo" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];


    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                              initWithKey:@"details.muscle" ascending:NO];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

// Sort Results
if ([self.title isEqual: @"Abdominals"]) {

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"details.muscle == %@", @"Back"];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

     }

else if ([self.title isEqual: @"Arms"]) {

        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"details.muscle == %@", @"Biceps"];
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate ];

    }

    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
    [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                        managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                   cacheName:@"Root"];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, if you use a `cacheName` with a fetched results controller you shouldn't change the fetch request.

If you do change the fetch request you must delete the cache, otherwise you get errors related to the cache contents no longer matching your fetched results.

If you want to change the fetch request you generally don't gain any benefit from having a cache.

Comment: Very simple and easy. I see that now. I changed the cache to nil and it fixed the error. The only issue I am having is targeting the if statement. The if is related to the title as in 'self.title isEqual: @"Arms"' but isn't working. Any quick thoughts?

Comment: `isEqual` should work, assuming the text actually matches. `isEqualToString` is more efficient. Log what the title is, it needs to be an exact match.

Comment: im setting the title statically on the storyboard. That be one of the issues?

Comment: Debugging is the only way to be sure what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

When you leave the view, you need in the tableViewController:

```
 -(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
     [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
     [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"Root"];
     self.fetchedResultsController = nil;

 }
```

And also:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"Root"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

or the best form is here (all together):

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"Root"];
        self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
    }
    return self;
}
```